# Expanding a SAS6IR array: what happens to the old disks?

Tags: backup, raid

Dell Poweredge, with two disks in RAID1 configuration through a SAS6IR controller.

This controller does not support virtual disk expansion, so what I need to do is to make a bare-metal backup, pull out both disks, swap in the two larger disks, re-create the RAID array and run a restore.

In my scenario it does not matter if the restore isn't synced - the files on the machine are being served statically and are not expected to change for long periods (think "static web site"). Access logs are also kept elsewhere.

Now, I have an older P300, with exactly identical hardware, that I plan on using to verify that the restore runs correctly. What I'm going to do is plug the new, empty disks into Old Faithful and run the restore, while the main machine is still online and Old Faithful is disconnected from the network.

My original plan was to then power down the main machine, plug the new disks into it, reconfigure the RAID, reinitialize the disks, and run again the restore.

But I wonder: what would happen if, after the restore successfully completed on the older, battered *but identical* machine, I powered down *both* machines, swapped the 2TB disks, and powered up again the main machine? Would the new 2TB disks be mis-recognized because the BIOS knows they should be 1TB? Is there a way to not-reinitialize the RAID array, telling the BIOS "assume the two disks are already fully synced" (which they would be)?

If this was possible I could perform the upgrade with very little downtime, since the new disks would be restored on another machine while the main server was still up and running. Considering that the SAS6IR won't let me enlarge online the virtual disk, it's probably too good to be true, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: These should be hot plug right?  Why not plug in new drives with machine on > initialize drive and build new array >  Create filesystem on new array > mirror files from old array to new array > migrate to use files on new array in OS and restart services?  Almost no downtime or risk?

Comment: Unfortunately both machines only have two bays. Weird, but that is the way it is. Yes, they are hot plug.

Comment: Could you use your old R?300 as a temporary server, mirror over things even to a single drive > serve from old server > work on migration on new server: creating new array, migrating arrays, power on and off, etc > then mirror back over?  Even if someone "answers" I am always trying to do a migration that allows for mistakes.  With the temporary active mirror, you can make a mistake and take time to recover while still being "active".

Comment: The RAID configuration is stored on the disks. Plug them in and the server will automatically pick it up and start using it. Yes, you can do exactly what you have described without issue.

Comment: Had not thought on this possibility. Yes, I could create two arrays in degraded mode with a single 2TB disk each. If the straight swap is not endorsed by anyone,  I will do it this way. I will still have the bare metal backup unit if things go really wrong.

Comment: @Appleoddity IMO your comment is technically the answer if it is correct.

Comment: I second that too as I've done the exact same thing on Dell PowerEdge 2850 servers in the past just as you explain. I just pushed the full OS image to the larger drives  and configured RAID of the non-production but identical hardware and confirmed it came up as expected afterwards but disconnected from the network and then did the swap with similar static data until a process occurs after hours, etc. It's been a while but I remember that from a few years back.